# Pluto 2.0 + MyFaces Portlet bridge + JSF 2.0 Application

Tags: jsf-2, portlet

Recently I have explored the possibilities to integrate a regular JSF 2.0 application as a portlet a portlal.

The first thing I've done is downloaded [Pluto 2.0](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/) (bundled with tomcat) and [Myfaces Portlet Bridge 2](http://myfaces.apache.org/portlet-bridge/2.0/index.html). I have created a small webapp ([Core JSF 2.0](http://horstmann.com/corejsf/) chapter 2 quiz application).
As I saw from the tutorials I have created portlet.xml file in WEB-INF with the following content:

```
<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd">

   <portlet>

        <portlet-name>QPortlet</portlet-name>
        <portlet-class>javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet</portlet-class>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <init-param>
        <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
        <value>faces/index.xhtml</value>
        </init-param>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>application/xhtml+xml</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>QPortlet</title>
            <short-title>QPortlet</short-title>
        </portlet-info>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

Then I added several lines in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>QPortlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>portlet-name</param-name>
        <param-value>QPortlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>QPortlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/PlutoInvoker/QPortlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Have copied the corresponding bridge Jar to the lib folder, packaged as war file and deployed to Pluto. Pluto itself recognized my webapp as a portlet.  Cool but when I opened the  window with the portlet it was just empty. The web application works nice separately, But not as a portlet. 
I have tried the examples from MyFaces but the most I can get is the following exception:

```
Error rendering portlet portlet-bridge-carstore.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only supported in a portlet environment
at org.apache.myfaces.portlet.faces.util.map.PortletRequestMap.(PortletRequestMap.java:42)
```

…

Am I doing something wrong?
I have also tried [JBoss Portlet Bridge](http://www.jboss.org/portletbridge), but I get the same result…